# Conversion of data to perform logistic regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-processing

I have a dataset which contains the data of cricket matches from 2010 to 2023. I have attached a sample of the data for reference:

| Team_1 | Team_2 | Ground | Matchdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bangladesh | Srilanka | Mirpur | 2010-01-04 |
| India | Australia | Edgbaston | 2010-08-15 |
| Southafrica | England | Barbados | 2016-07-03 |
| India | England | Lords | 2015-06-10 |

I am trying to create a logistic regression model and I recieve this error message:

```
#Create regression model
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
trf = ColumnTransformer([('trf', OneHotEncoder(sparse= False, drop= 'first'),['Team_1','Team_2','Ground'])], remainder = 'passthrough')
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('step1',trf),('step2', LogisticRegression(solver = 'liblinear'))])
pipe.fit(X_train, Y_train)`
```

Error Message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'India'
```

I tried HotEncoding the Team_1, Team_2 and Ground columns to use in my logistic regression

Comment: The error you're seeing, ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'India', is due to the fact that the logistic regression model cannot handle string values directly. You're on the right track by trying to use one-hot encoding to convert categorical string values into a numerical format that the model can understand.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down the steps to fix this:

1. **Ensure Proper Data Splitting**: Before applying transformations, ensure that you've split your data into training and test sets (`X_train`, `X_test`, `Y_train`, `Y_test`).
2. **ColumnTransformer & OneHotEncoder**: You're using `ColumnTransformer` with `OneHotEncoder` which is correct. Ensure that the columns you're trying to transform actually exist in `X_train`.
3. **Fit and Transform**: When you use `pipe.fit(X_train, Y_train)`, it will first apply the transformations specified in the pipeline and then fit the logistic regression model.

Here's a more detailed approach:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# Sample data
data = {
    'Team_1': ['Bangladesh', 'India', 'Southafrica', 'India'],
    'Team_2': ['Srilanka', 'Australia', 'England', 'England'],
    'Ground': ['Mirpur', 'Edgbaston', 'Barbados', 'Lords'],
    'Matchdate': ['2010-01-04', '2010-08-15', '2016-07-03', '2015-06-10']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Assuming you have a target column named 'target'
X = df.drop(columns=['Matchdate'])  # Dropping Matchdate for simplicity
y = df['Matchdate']  # This is just a placeholder, replace with your actual target column

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Create regression model
trf = ColumnTransformer([('trf', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, drop='first'), ['Team_1', 'Team_2', 'Ground'])], remainder='passthrough')
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('step1', trf), ('step2', LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear'))])
pipe.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Note:

- Ensure that `X_train` and `Y_train` are correctly defined and have the expected data.
- The sample data uses 'Matchdate' as the target variable just for demonstration purposes. In a real-world scenario, you'd have a different target variable (like match outcome) for logistic regression.